# How much size of multiple images/videos can i select and upload at once

Tags: java, android, image

Am going to work on uploading & displaying multiple images/videos on my app, i searched a lot but what i couldn't figure out is how much size of images/videos can i select and upload at once.

Can anyone help me with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's not a simple answer for this, it depends on LOTS of factors, such as internet speed, phone hardware specs, OS version, etc.

Comment: Thanks . . . . . .